# Disable Syntax Highlight in Sphinx (Alabaster theme)

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How to disable syntax highlight in Sphinx?

I've tried setting [highlight language to 'none'](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-highlight_language) and [setting ..language:: none](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html#showing-code-examples).

Also tried [setting it to 'text'](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#pygments.lexers.special.TextLexer).

I tried removing the html and `make clean`. But the syntax highlighting is there. (using Alabaster theme)

`conf.py` is configured with these extensions:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
    'numpydoc',
    ]
```

EDIT: Well it seems that `viewcode` extension is doing this and that [it is quite hard coded](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/bf3f9ef3ecc94067a2f9b17f2c863e723cf3e7af/sphinx/ext/viewcode.py#L159)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/3714).. fixed in 1.6-release

Answer (score 2):

`viewcode` applies syntax highlighting only to Python source files. To disable highlighting in just those files, you could edit the source of the file by modifying this line in the `lexer` logic adding `, 'none'`.

```
    if env.config.highlight_language in ('python3', 'default', 'none'):
```

It looks like you already submitted a [PR for it](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/3700).

For all other files rendered by Sphinx in your narrative documentation, you can disable highlighting globally in `conf.py`:

```
highlight_language ='none'
```

Then this would be inherited by your modification in `viewcode`.